# Ruby on Rails. Large condition in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, conditional-statements

I'm faced a situation unfamiliar to me and I need advice.
There is a controller with the action 'update'

```
def update
  @arrival = find_arrival
  @details = @arrival.arrival_details

  if check_conditions(@arrival)
    flash[:notice] = 'Документ прихода отредактирован'
  else
    flash[:error] = 'Возникла ошибка. Проверьте правильность заполнения формы'
  end
  redirect_to edit_admin_arrival_path(@arrival)
end
```

and few private methods:

```
def check_conditions(arrival)
  new_status = arrival_params[:status]

  case @arrival.status
  when 'draft'
    return unless check_dependencies
    recalculate_balance if new_status == 'accrued'
    @arrival.update(arrival_params)
  when 'canceled'
    return unless new_status == 'draft'
    @arrival.update(status: arrival_params[:status])
  when 'accrued'
    return if new_status == 'draft'
    recalculate_balance if new_status == 'canceled'
    @arrival.update(new_status)
  end
end

def recalculate_balance
  puts '[PRY] recalculated'
end

def check_dependencies
  Provider.exists?(arrival_params[:provider_id]) &&
  Warehouse.exists?(arrival_params[:warehouse_id])
end
```

I'm interested in the following - do I need to move this condition to a separate class or some Service Object for example? I do not think that this huge condition should be in the controller. What can you advise?

Comment: https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine

Comment: @Зелёный Just out of curiosity, is the state_machine gem still the way to go, it hasn't been updated in 4-5 years?

Comment: It's pure ruby with zero dependensies and works good for me, in the Rails and other apps.

Comment: @Iceman there's also https://github.com/state-machines/state_machines

Comment: @Stefan Thanks, that looks more convincing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely, it's not a Controller logic. Slim controllers are preferred. Better move this one to a service object, or to `Arrival` class and use as an arrival instance object method `@arrival.check_conditions`.

And I'd recommend to use state machine here: https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine